# Spring mvc download file without asking

Tags: file, spring-mvc, download, dialog, window

I work with Spring MVC and I want to download a pdf. I don't want to show the following dialog window

[image]

I don't want to show "Do you want open or save .....?".
I want to open directly the file in the screen.

I wrote the following method:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/visualizarmanual", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public HttpEntity<byte[]> descargarManual(@RequestParam("directorioDocumentacion") String directorioDocumentacion,
            @RequestParam("nombreDocumento") String nombreDocumentoP,HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException, Exception {
        // convert JSON to Employee 
        logger.info("DocumentacionController descargarManual principio ");
        String  nombreDocumento = "springEcalcpAdmin.properties";
        logger.info("DocumentacionController descargarManual nombreDocumento "+nombreDocumento);

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/plain"));

        headers.setContentDispositionFormData(nombreDocumento, nombreDocumento);
        byte[] documentBody = crearFichero(request,nombreDocumento);
        headers.setCacheControl("must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        ResponseEntity<byte[]> response = new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(documentBody, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
        return response;
    }
```

Is there a way to download the file without asking?

Answer (score 0):

You can deal with this with content disposition.

If you want to open the file like a webpage, you need to specify it as inline.

```
Content-Disposition: inline
```

If you want to download the file, you need to specify it as attachment. If you want to specify the name of the downloaded file you can use filename, but this is not mandatory.

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename.jpg"
```

You can see more here

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition